# Web Video player with API access

Tags: video, html5-video, video-processing

Does anyone know web video player which have API to manipulate video output. 
For example rotate or select just a fragment from full video and play just it?
The main task is video editor and we have server side implementation for video manipulation but now we need web UI for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dependng on the type and level of on-the fly processing that you require you could potentially  use html5 video and canvas features, e.g. here is the first promising tutorial that pops up with a google search: http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/

Comment: Thanks. It seems it's powerful solution.